# How to convert Pandas Series to Timestamp when not every value is convertible?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, machine-learning, timestamp

**Context**

I have a `Pandas` `Series` containing `Dates` in a `String` format *(e.g. 2017-12-19 09:35:00)*. My goal is to convert this `Series` into `Timestamps` *(Time in Seconds since 1970)*.

The difficulty is, that some `Values` in this `Series` are corrupt and cannot be converted to a `Timestamp`. In that case, they should be converted to `None`.

---

**Code**

```py
import datetime

series = series.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())
```

---

**Question**

> The code above would work when all `Values` are in the correct format, however there is corrupt data.

- How can I achieve my goal while converting all not-convertible data to `None`?

Comment: why do you need to use `None` as a no-value identifier?  For pandas datetime, there is `NaT` ("no-a-time"), for float, there is `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function with try except, like this:

```
def to_timestamp(x):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()
    except:
        return None

series = series.apply(to_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas typically represents invalid timestamps with `NaT` (Not a Time). You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors="coerce"`:

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(["2023-01-07 12:34:56", "error"])
out = pd.to_datetime(series, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", errors="coerce")
```

output:

```
0   2023-01-07 12:34:56
1                   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```